# Do cards that prevent cards in graveyards from being targeted by spells and abilities stop cards such as Crucible of Worlds?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent has [Ground Seal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGround%20Seal%5d) in play and I have a [Crucible of Worlds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrucible%20of%20Worlds%5d), can I still play lands from my graveyard? I know [Crucible of Worlds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrucible%20of%20Worlds%5d) says nothing about targeting, so I assume it would not stop me from playing lands from my graveyard.

Some other cards that I assume would fall under the same roof as [Crucible of Worlds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrucible%20of%20Worlds%5d) are [Karador, Ghost Chieftain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarador%2c%20Ghost%20Chieftain%5d) and [Gisa and Geralf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGisa%20and%20Geralf%5d).

Comment: MTG's logic is boolean. It either uses the word target and it targets or it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your intuition is exactly correct - Crucible of Worlds doesn't *target* the land cards, so Ground Seal doesn't prevent it from working.

This is reinforced in the [Gatherer rulings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=451104) for Ground Seal:

> Only spells and abilities that target cards in graveyards will be affected. Abilities that don’t target cards in graveyards (like the one Tormod’s Crypt has) can still affect those cards.

Comment: Alright. I assumed it was that way, but I wanted to make sure, as the combos and synergies Crucible of Worlds can give are rather powerful.

Comment: I am not sure that is a comparable card to use. Tormod's Crypt doesn't target cards because it targets the entire graveyard. "Sacrifice Tormod's Crypt: Exile all cards from target player's graveyard."

Comment: I am going to update the question with some other cards with similar effects.

Comment: @JoeW Actually, it targets a player, not a graveyard.

Comment: @Arthur Good point, not sure how I missed that when looking at it. But still doesn't target cards in the graveyard.

Comment: @JoeW That's the whole point though... it doesn't target a card in the graveyard, exactly like Crucible of Worlds.